# Equal step-slicing a list by keeping minimum and maximum

Tags: python, slice

I need to get an "equal" step slicing from a linear integer list (which could not start from 0), but with the following requirements:

- the last value (the maximum) always has to appear
- there must not be an interval lower than the step (most importantly, between the next to last and last values)
- given the point above, some intervals might be higher than the step, and those intervals must be placed equally between the resulting list
- only standard library functions should be used (no numpy)

Some examples:

- with a list from `range(10)` and step 2, the result should be one of the following:

  `[0, 2, 5, 7, 9]`
  `[0, 2, 4, 7, 9]`
- with `range(21)` and step 3:

  `[0, 3, 7, 10, 14, 17, 20]`
- with `range(1, 22)` and step 3:

  `[1, 4, 8, 11, 15, 18, 21]`

Right now I've got something similar to this, which obviously does not work properly:

```
def getSlices(l, s):
    skipCount = (len(l) - 1) % s
    divCount = int(len(l) / (skipCount + 1))

    o = []
    for delta, skip in enumerate(range(skipCount + 1)):
        o.extend(l[skip * divCount + delta:(skip + 1) * divCount + delta:s])
    return o

>>> getSlices(list(range(21)), 3)
[0, 3, 6, 8, 11, 14, 16, 19]
```

I know I could just cycle through all values, skip by correlating `enumerate` indexes and steps, and add a "delta" as soon as a new "portion" of the list is reached, but that doesn't seem the most performing solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could go the way you want. Hope it helps.

```py
def getSlices(l, step):

    init = l[0]
    last = l[-1]  # exclude last element (remove as you want)

    slices = (last-init) // step + 1
    mod = (last-init) % step
    even = mod // 2
    mid = slices // 2 - 1
    even_start = mid - even
    even_end = mid + mod - even

    final = []

    val = init
    for i in range(slices):
        final.append(val)
        val += step

        # Distribute mod unitary in the middle
        if slices-1 >= mod:
            if mod > 0 and (even_start <= i <= even_end):
                val += 1
                # In case is the middle don't change it
                if i == mid:
                    val += - 1

        # Distribute mod evenly all across the slices
        else:
            val += mod // (slices-1)
            # In case a there is mod left, place it just in the middle
            if i == mid:
                val += mod % (slices-1)

    return final

# Examples:
#
# getSlices(list(range(10)), 2)
# [0, 2, 4, 7, 9]
#
# getSlices(list(range(21)), 3)
# [0, 3, 7, 10, 14, 17, 20]
#
# getSlices(list(range(1, 22)), 3)
# [1, 4, 8, 11, 15, 18, 21]
#
# getSlices(list(range(36)), 10)
# [0, 11, 24, 35]
```